# Microsoft Bot Framework Unable to get the passed username in the bot from webchat UI

Tags: botframework, bots

I am using the latest version of the web chat as below
``

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <style>
html, body { height: 100% }
 body { margin: 0 }

 #webchat {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
 }
</style>
  <body>
    <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/master/webchat.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token: 'MY_TOKEN_FROM_AZURE' }),
        userID: '1234',
        username: 'Chinni',
        locale: 'en-US',
        botAvatarInitials: 'WC',
        userAvatarInitials: 'WW'
      }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

``

I sent a username from the renderwebchat() but the same is not accessible in the bot

```
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(turnContext.Activity.From.Name), cancellationToken);
```

The output is null in the web chat. Can someone help me over here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may have a mistake somewhere in your implementation, because I confirm that it is working. As you can see, I have the values available:

[image: Demo]

On the bot side, here is how I send those messages:

```
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(turnContext.Activity));
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Value of 'turnContext.Activity.From.Id': '{turnContext.Activity.From.Id}', 'turnContext.Activity.From.Name': '{turnContext.Activity.From.Name}'");
```

And on the webchat demo page, I used the same code as yours (except that I used my own token)

Comment: Thank you so much. But I'm trying to extract the name in the conversation update method and i'm getting null over there. The reason why I want the name in the conversationUpdate is for the welcome message to greet the user with his/her name like Good Morning Chinni How may I help you today.

Comment: So you are doing it the wrong way: welcoming the user in the webchat must be done through a custom event that you manage from the Webchat code, as the `ConversationUpdate` containing details about the user will be sent only once your user has sent a message. See a great sample here on how to welcome your user: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.d.backchannel-send-welcome-event